# How to spy on the argument passed in a method?

Tags: angular, jasmine

I want to check if the line: slidingItem.close() inside setTimeout() is executed. The line inside the setTimeout() is the argument passed in the method. How can I test the line inside setTimeout. I added the spec file below for reference.

```
  onCompleteActivity(_activity, slidingItem: ItemSliding) {
      this.store.dispatch(new activitiesActions.SelectActivity(_activity));
      this.utilService.openPage(
        ActivityCompletionPageComponent, true,
        {
          leadId: _activity.leadId, fromSchedList: true
        }
      );
      setTimeout(function() {
        slidingItem.close();
      }, 1000);
  }
```

spec.ts:

```
 it('should open: ActivityCompletionPageComponent on onCompleteActivity', fakeAsync(() => {
    spyOn(component.utilService, 'openPage');
    spyOn(component.slidingItem, 'close');
    component.onCompleteActivity(activity, component.slidingItem);
    expect(component.utilService.openPage).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(component.utilService.openPage).toHaveBeenCalledWith(ActivityCompletionPageComponent,
      true,
      {
        leadId: activity.leadId,
        fromSchedList: true
      })

    tick(1000);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(component.slidingItem.close).toHaveBeenCalled()
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can added the console.log so that you can know it is is the setTimeout function

```
console.log("inside timeout ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `logger`.

As this is for debugging purpose I believe, you can use `Logger.logLevel= 'debug'` for your dev environment. If you need to know it in other environments, you can use `info` level logs